# Use both ahref and onclick on php to hIde parameters?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php function which gets data from database and calls a javasript function like this:

```
echo "<p><a href=\"javascript: customm('$variable')\">$header</a></p>";
```

The problem is when someone hovers over the link, the browser shows the complete parameters like this:(on bottom left of the browser, or a new tab)

```
javascript: customm('some secret code here');
```

Is there a way to hide this? I tried adding onclick to the php function and pointing ahref to #.

```
echo "<p><a href='#' onclick='javascript: customm('$variable')'>$header</a></p>";
```

But it didnot work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get rid of `javascript:` and see what happens. Also, your quotes are conflicting in your last example.

Comment: thanks, i fixed the quote. without javascript or with javascript, the onlick is not being called. if i add javascript function to ahref then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked:

```
echo "<p><a href = '#' onclick=\"javascript: customm('$variable')\">$header</a></p>";
```

Thanks KaeruCT and Blender!

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you need to escape the quotes:

```
echo "<p><a href='#' onclick='customm(\"$variable\"); return false;'>$header</a></p>";
```

Comment: Thanks KaeruCt. For some reason, javascript function is not being called! If I add the javascript function to ahref, it works. any idea?

Comment: oh, i forgot to remove 'javascript: ' from my answer, see the edit

Comment: thanks again. I tried it with javascript and without javascript with a simple alert function but no luck. if i add javascript: alert("Hi"); on href it works, but not on onclick!

Comment: my mistake again, I put the wrong kind of quotes... try with the new edit I made

Comment: Didnot work, This code worked: 
echo "<p><a href = '#' onclick=\"javascript: customm('$variable')\">$header</a></p>";